# Python 3 sequences: String and Lists

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

I am working through John Zelle's book Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science. I'm now doing the programming exercises at the end of chapter 5; which covered sequences: string, Lists, and Files.

I was able to create programs for questions #1 and #2, however I had been stuck on finding a solution for question #3 (below), so I used the solution guide to get the answer. The problem is I don't understand complete how the solution works!

For example how does this equation work? `grades = 60 * "F" + 10 * "D" + 10 * "C" + 10 * "B" + 11 * "A"`

I believe once I have a better understand of how the equation works, I'll be able to figure out how the program is able to find the corresponding grade to print. `print("The grade is", grades[score])`

I've back tracked chapter 5 to see if there was anything I missed but I don't see any examples relevant to the solution to this question.

> 3. A certain CS professor gives 100-point exams that are graded on the scale 90-100:A, 80-89:B, 70-79:C, 60-69:D, <60:F. Write a program that
>      ac­cepts an exam score as input and prints out the corresponding
>      grade.

solution:

```
def main():

    score = int(input("Enter grade number: "))
    grades = 60 * "F" + 10 * "D" + 10 * "C" + 10 * "B" + 11 * "A"
    print("The grade is", grades[score])

main()
```

Comment: Why not `print(grades)` and find out?

Comment: That’s what I end up doing, and was able to comprehend what was going on in the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the equation creates a string. 60 F then 10 D.  like FFF... DDD...... AAA
it your score is between 0 to 59 then grades[score] will return the value of the corresponding index of that string (F in this case).

https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P70oMSW1WMFWwcxAQUtByU1JQVvBEMx0QTCdEUwnMNMQxHRU4iooyswr0YCYoamAwo02tYxVQBczMwCJ/f8PAA

Answer (score 0):

His solution creates a string holding a letter for each number between 0 and 100.

The variable `grades` evaluates to

`FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFDDDDDDDDDDCCCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAA`

From that, the grade is just the letter corresponding to the score.